# Why is session lost between SOME pages, not all?

Tags: php, session

I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm struggling with my webshop.

I have a drop down menu on my site with one menu option containing all product categories in the webshop. As long as I'm navigating between these categories my session is persistent and working fine (I'm putting products in a shopping bag and I can move to the cart and go through with the whole order). But if I go to a page in another drop down menu option "outside" the webshop (like the contact page) my session is lost. I have used pretty much the same template to create these pages, but they are of course more simple with mostly text content (apart from the cart that is always accessible from the top menu).

The first page outside the webshop drop down menu option is ok with the correct session id, but when I move to the second page the session is gone. It doesn't matter in which order I visit the pages. The first one is always working but the following ones are not.

What on earth can be causing this behaviour? On every page I start with this piece of code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
...
```

Further down I include the cart in the top menu:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/includes/right-cart.inc";
include_once($path);
```

And in the included cart code I use this line for the session id:

```
$currSession = session_id();
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

I tried to add some error logging and noticed something interesting. I now start my files with this (just to find out some more information):

```
<?php
phpinfo();
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../session'));
session_start();
// create session variable if it doesn't exist yet
if (isset($_SESSION['counter']))
  $_SESSION['counter'] ++;
else
  $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;

var_dump($_SESSION); echo "<br/>\n";
var_dump(session_id()); echo "<br/>\n";
var_dump(session_name()); echo "<br/>\n";
var_dump(session_get_cookie_params()); echo "<br/>\n";
?>
```

As long as I have the first row, phpinfo();, the session seems to be the same. But if I remove that line the session keeps renewing when refreshing the page...

**EDIT 2**

After a suggestion I tried to use a cookie to store a "session id" instead of a regular session. The code at the top of my page now seems like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$currSession = "";
$cookie_name = "sessionId";
$cookie_value = "";
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    $cookie_value = session_id();
    setcookie(  $cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (60*60*24*2), "/");
}
if(count($_COOKIE) > 0) {
    $currSession = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
} else {
    $currSession = session_id();
}
?>
```

But everytime I reload the page also the cookie value seems to change. I have tried different echo statements in the code to verify what happens but everything looks right (the cookie is created successfully, the isset function tells me that the cookie actually is set etc), but still the value in the cookie changes. Any ideas?

Comment: The second page is in the same subdomain as the first one?

Comment: Yes, they are all on the same subdomain. In the same folder on the server as well.

Comment: And it's a shared host I should add maby (or whatever it's called...) :-)

Comment: Is the page changing from www.yourdomain to yourdomain.com or vice versa?

Comment: And you are positive that `session_unset()` and/or `session_destroy()` are not called upon leaving one page, as well as loading the new one? Also, switching back and forth between SSL (https) can cause this, I'm sure your cart page is secure....

Comment: I only use relative urls so there are no changing between www or not (I also double checked that).

And I'm 100% sure I'm not using session_unset() or session_destroy() since I didn't even know they existed (as I said, I'm pretty new to php, trying to convert my old classic ASP site...) :-)

And no SSL either...
I'm getting crazy over here. I just don't understand this strange behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that... I tried to put the var_dump code under the session_start but then I get the following message when loading the webpage: Notice: Use of undefined constant session_get_cookie_params. I suppose I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Hmm...if I echo that line I get this: array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(0) "" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) }. What does that mean?

Comment: You should seriosuly look where you store your session files. And check if a new session file is generated. usually is `/tmp` folder.

Comment: Do you have any error logging set up? Please check over Stack Overflow and install some errorlogging to see if any warnings or notices are thrown by PHP. Things like session cache overflow and similar. Unable to write session data due to insufficient space, etc.

Comment: @Elias How do I check that? I dont have a /tmp folder or any other folder that I can see in my ftp account.

Comment: Ok, now I finally managed to add some error logging. The lines stored in the log file is: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent. I also noticed another thing but I think I have to write that in a separate answer to make it readable...

Comment: Now I've added a new observation to my first post (look for "EDIT"). I hope someone can get a clue out of this! Personally I have to go to sleep now since it's the middle of the night here so I will keep trying tomorrow again. Thanks for now! Hoping for some new insights tomorrow :-)

Comment: Thanks @Ryan! That might be a great solution - to just skip the regular session id and create a cookie instead holding a personal kind of session id. Bu just a question about cookies: are there any known problem with them? Nowadays you have to have a popup telling your visitors that "this site use cookies", but is there anything else I should know? I will try this solution tomorrow and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: @RyanVincent Now I've tried to implement a cookie based kind of session id instead. But it doesn't work. Everytime the page reloads also the cookie value seems to change, even though I don't think I'm actually changing it. Here is the code I have at the top of my page now:

Comment: <?php
session_start();
$currSession = "";
$cookie_name = "sessionId";
$cookie_value = "";
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
 $cookie_value = session_id();
 setcookie( $cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (60*60*24*2), "/");
}
if(count($_COOKIE) > 0) {
    $currSession = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
} else {
    $currSession = session_id();
}
?>

Comment: You should try and set that session id cookie yourself – PHP is perfectly capable of handling that itself, if you just configure your session parameters right.

Comment: probably, on the pages where you don't get the session to work you have some chars before the session start command. This will make your session start to fail. Can you check it? Headers already sent means that php has started rendering the page and only after you declare the session (it should be the opposite)

Comment: @CBroe I'm not sure if I'm following. Do you mean that I should use an own id to store in the cookie, instead of storing the id generated from session_id()?

Comment: @LelioFaieta I'm pretty sure there are no chars before the session start command. I have checked that several times and I have also copied the code from the working pages with no success.

Comment: Oh, by the way. I also tried to take one of the working pages and just renamed it so it replaced one of the not working pages. Guess what - the page doesn't work any more! Could it be some kind of problem with the url/folder or similar? I know a cookie must be saved in the right destination so I have uset "/" for it to work everywhere (which didn't help, but anyway). Is there something similar with session?

Comment: _“Do you mean that I should use an own id to store in the cookie, instead of storing the id generated from session_id()?”_ – sorry, that was missing a “not” – I meant that you should let PHP’s session mechanism handle setting of the cookie that stores the session id. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me! Now I have finally solved it. An easy fix, but really hard to find. I just changed the quotes in this line: setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (60*60*24*2), "/"); to setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (60*60*24*2), "/"); and suddenly it works :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the question so I thought I'll post the answer here in case someone else is having trouble.

I changed this line ("/"):

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (60*60*24*2), "/");
```

to ('/')

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (60*60*24*2), '/');
```

and suddenly it works! :-)

Comment: Not sure why you want to create your own [session_id cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) though

Comment: @DarkBee Well, my original post was about problems with my session_id since the session wasn't consistent between pages. Ryan suggested another solution based on cookies instead and I got that one to work. But if you have a solution to my original problem with the sessions I would be more then happy if you would like to share :-)